# Class parameter name for default type in spring-kafka listener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, spring-kafka

I'm attempting to change the default type value for kafka listener with property  "spring.json.value.default.type=" using my own annotation in spring-kafka. Currently, it's possible to overwrite it with following values:
properties="spring.json.value.default.type=com.package.class" which is canonical name of class.
I've made an annotation that sets the following value:

```
@MyAnnotation(topic = Topics.BUILD_CONFIG_CREATED, defaultType = ConstantsClass.TYPE_HEADER + "prz.student.finger.kafkaBSC.MyObjectDTO")
```

Is there any way to avoid hard typing the class name?
I would like to implement the option to use the following code(just giving the class that was imported):

```
@MyAnnotation(topic = Topics.BUILD_CONFIG_CREATED, defaultType = MyObjectDTO.class)
```

The closest to I've got is adding in my annotation:

```
@AliasFor(annotation = KafkaListener.class, attribute = "properties")
    String defaultType() default headerType()+dtoType().getCanonicalName().toString();
String headerType() default "spring.json.value.default.type=";
```

Unfortunately, the constraints regarding the compilation time values for class in annotation blocks me from implementing it. Is there any way to inject the cannonical name without hard typing it, or any other way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

The `properties` property can contain SpEL (see its Javadocs).

Something like `#{@someBean.type.name}`; where `someBean` is a bean with a method `public Class<?> getType()`.

Comment: Great clue. I've read the docs but didn't understand at first what that was. Thank you very much!

Comment: Or it can be a property `${type.name}`.